# Server not receiving UDP packets, been spending hours trying to figure out what's wrong

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, winsock

So for our first assignment we made a basic ftp program using TCP, now we have to modify it to use UDP, also sending it to a router program (that we cannot modify, but have the code to look at) that will randomly drop and delay packets and handle it with a simple stop and wait protocol. But that's not the problem.

I modified the Client and Server to use UDP using the notes from my lab teacher (http://www.cs.concordia.ca/~ste_mors/comp445/Assign2tutorial.ppt) and all I'm doing is sending a packet and when I receive it on the other end print a line of text. I followed the instructions in the slides, running it on localhost (have no other machines to test with) and it sends, and the router confirms it receives and forwards the packet, but the server never prints the line of text. Knowing that UDP drops packets a lot I made a while(true) loop that sends packets forever, the server still does nothing.

Here's the code so far:
Client: http://pastebin.com/XdbxuJ9R
Server: http://pastebin.com/iN5j2Ku3
Unmodifiable Router given to us: http://pastebin.com/QwMAc0MW

For the client i left in everything after the connection starts from the old one, the send line is 175, in server I commented out everything in the run loop except the receive part which is at line 181

I'm going absolutely crazy trying to fix this. I had to cancel plans and ruin my entire day because I can't get this one thing working. :(

Comment: One not-so-obvious problem could be a firewall on your PC :)

Comment: Only windows firewall, in windows 7, I allowed it when the pop ups came up. They only came up for router and server.

Comment: Just turned it off (with my internet as well, can't be too careful :P) Same issue. One odd thing that happens is the router output shows that it passes it along, then shows a message implying the server sent something, but I only have a receive in my server, no sends of any kind.

Comment: @paulsm4 Forgot to @ reply you.

Comment: I have implemented the same functionality but in java.I hope you find it useful.here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/4x94gr32ly5fehn/1.txt.

Comment: Thanks, but not as much, it looks so much easier in Java. The one non-game class that doesn't use Java...I have no idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what i can tell you're using the wrong ports. Here's what the router.h defines:

```
// router.h
#define ROUTER_PORT1 7000 //router port number 1
#define ROUTER_PORT2 7001 //router port number 2
#define PEER_PORT1 5000   //port number of peer host 1
#define PEER_PORT2 5001   //port number of peer host 2
```

And here's what you're defining:

```
// client.cpp
#define REQUEST_PORT 0x5000 // hexadecimal, that's port 20480
```

and

```
// server.cpp
#define REQUEST_PORT 0x5001 // hexadecimal, that's port 20481
```

I didn't check the rest of the code, but the server appeared to receive something after correcting the port numbers (as in removing the `0x` prefix)

Maybe this will help illustrate how the router works:

```
// the router does (pseudocode):
recvfrom(7000), sendto(PEER2:5001)
recvfrom(7001), sendto(PEER1:5000)
```

Comment: Oh no...how didn't I notice this. >_< I even changed the value a bunch without removing the 0x prefix! Thank you so much! I was luckily able to get a week extension and I didn't reveal why my code wasn't running. :P

Comment: server.cpp and client.cpp should #include router.h :)